# How to install JDK 1.5 for Solaris 10

Tags: java

I been trying to install but keep on getting file is corrupted when unpacking the file after accepting the license agreement.

Anyone have any advice.

http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index_jdk5.jsp

I installing this jdk-1_5_0_17-solaris-sparc.sh

Comment: but i cam using sftp-3 as the file transfer protocol using the software winscp. How do i configure to use binary mode?

Comment: Most ftp programs automatically assumes `.sh` file is a text file. Easiest way is to rename it to something like `.sh.dat` or whatever. Then transfer it and rename it back to `.sh`

Answer (score 3):

Installer (jdk-1_5_0_17-solaris-sparc.sh)  is a script which contains two parts: text part (up to a license agreement) and binary part (zipped data, the JDK itself).

File is corrupted in the second, binary part.

My guess is that you're transferring installer by FTP without using binary mode. If you're using plain vanilla ftp, just type "bin" before you download the file. If that's another FTP client, consult help.